# HTML interactive canvas behind text while maintaining text clickability

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am working on a webpage where I need to place an interactive HTML canvas behind some text content.

How can I create an interactive canvas behind text in such a way that the text and links in front of it remain clickable, but the canvas is also visible and can be interacted with? Are there specific HTML/CSS strategies or JavaScript techniques recommended for this setup?

The canvas has a brush effect, where you click to draw. My challenge is to ensure that while the canvas remains interactive and visible behind the text, the text (especially links) overlaying the canvas stays clickable.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFC0CB';
  ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.lineWidth = 90;
  ctx.shadowBlur = 30;
  ctx.shadowColor = '#FFC0CB';

  let isDrawing = false;
  let lastX = 0;
  let lastY = 0;

  function draw(e) {
    if (!isDrawing) return;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
    ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    ctx.stroke();
    [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
  }

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    isDrawing = true;
    [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
  });

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => isDrawing = false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', () => isDrawing = false);
});
```

```css
.drawing-canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -10;
}

p {
  z-index: 2
}

a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut scelerisque, tempor nec mattis sapien sed nostra litora. Nunc aliquam dignissim euismod egestas suscipit <a>CLICKABLE LINK</a> suspendisse cubilia dapibus, habitant ullamcorper vehicula mollis
  montes odio varius a, sed potenti condimentum augue natoque senectus erat libero sagittis, litora purus <a>CLICKABLE LINK</a> mauris justo neque hac. Dictum convallis bibendum nam habitant justo sociis mollis feugiat malesuada, leo molestie sem natoque
  facilisis fames torquent sociosqu conubia, <a>CLICKABLE LINK</a> duis senectus vivamus phasellus tortor consequat nulla. Justo sociosqu vestibulum hendrerit odio senectus curabitur ante neque primis urna aliquam eleifend consequat <a>CLICKABLE LINK</a>  tortor, facilisis hac mi habitasse egestas vehicula in vel lacus luctus fringilla suspendisse nostra. Placerat imperdiet ullamcorper nostra penatibus cras varius, primis tortor leo sociis pharetra, pretium felis ac faucibus sagittis. Penatibus sed <a>CLICKABLE LINK</a>  egestas sem facilisis tempor lacinia viverra, consequat semper justo suspendisse porttitor conubia feugiat nisl euismod, posuere tempus libero augue morbi ac ut.</p>
<canvas id="canvas" class="drawing-canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: How exactly do you expect this to work? When you click in-between the lines of the text, should the background be drawn on? And when you try to click the link, should it also happen or not?

Comment: I'd like the text to not be selectable (no highlighting), so that I can draw through the text. But i'd still like to be able to interact with links and clickable items.

Comment: And it is also okay to appear when you click the link too.

Comment: would [pointer-events: none](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#description) solve the issue for you, if you put your element on top and let pointer events pass through it to the element underneath?

Comment: Pointer-events: none placed on the text element seems to prevent all drawing through the text to the background

Comment: Apply `pointer-events: none` to the `<p>`, but then you'll also have to re-enable clicks (`pointer-events: all`) on `<a>`'s contained in the `<p>`. This allows the links to still be clickable. In any case, yes, your concept of content hovering `canvas` is possible; I've done it a few times.

Comment: Thank you everyone. It works now :) One on my issues was that I forgot the `relative` positioning and higher `z-index` on the text. So the correct solution is `<p>` elements with `position: relative`, higher `z-index` than the `canvas` element, `pointer-events: none`, except for `pointer-events: all` on the anchor tags.